# UITableView InsertRows (insertRowsAtIndexPaths) only animates one of two sections

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview, xamarin.ios

Before the table update, my table datasource has only one section with one row:

- Section 0

  - Row [0,0]

After the update the data source returns two more sections, each with only one row:

- Section 0

  - Row [0,0]
- Section 1

  - Row [1,0]
- Section 2

  - Row [2,0]

I use the following code to animate the table update:

```
// update the table data source, without reloading the table
UpdateTable();       

TableView.BeginUpdates();

// insert sections 1 and 2
TableView.InsertSections(NSIndexSet.FromNSRange(new NSRange(1, 2)), UITableViewRowAnimation.Fade);

// insert two new rows, one for each new section (rows [1,0] and [2,0])
TableView.InsertRows(new NSIndexPath[] { NSIndexPath.FromRowSection(0, 1), NSIndexPath.FromRowSection(0, 2) }, UITableViewRowAnimation.Fade);

TableView.EndUpdates();
```

However, only section 1 and its row are animated. Section 2 (with row [2,0]) appears instantly and does not move/fade a bit. I also checked with "Slow Animations" toggled.

What is wrong with this code?

**Edit:** I forgot to mention, the problem exists also if I omit the `InsertRows` call, which is unnecessary according Sam's answer.

Comment: When I try this code on a test view + table view of 4 sections, executed from the ViewDidAppear event, I get the following error: NSInternalInconsistencyException Reason: Invalid update: invalid number of sections.  The number of sections contained in the table view after the update (4) must be equal to the number of sections contained in the table view before the update (4), plus or minus the number of sections inserted or deleted (2 inserted, 0 deleted).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found out why: I was creating a new `UITableViewSource` instance every time `UpdateTable()` was invoked. This went all fine and well, except for some details when animating the changing of the table sections and rows.

When I changed the code to reuse the `UITableViewSource` instance, everything worked as expected.

Answer (score 1):

When inserting a section you do not need to animate individual rows.  Just call insert section code.  Also, similarly when removing a section you do not need to remove rows within.

Comment: Also, you should really be calling UpdateTable() between your call to beginUpdates and endUpdates on your UITableView.  This isn't causing you problems, but it is the proper way to do it

Comment: Thank you, I tried both suggestions, but neither one changed anything.